# Animate Tikz image with random coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, animate, random

I would like to do a Tikz image animation of growing lines with a certain randomness with regard to their initial rotation angle (and potentially also with a certain randomness in their initial x and y coordinates). I am aware that Tikz provides a rand and a random function (see example code) which work nicely for static images. However, inside of an animation they create a new random number for each frame. How could the random number be passed such that it is only evaluated initially?

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{animate}

\begin{document}

\begin{animateinline}[autoplay, loop]{24}
    \multiframe{100}{ry=0.05+0.02}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \x in {0,1,...,5}
        {
        \draw [thick, rotate around={random*10:(\x,0)}] ({\x},0) -- ++(0,\ry);
        }
        \path [use as bounding box] (0,0) rectangle (5,2.1);
    \end{tikzpicture}}
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example animation obtained with code above]

Comment: Have you tried to set a seed? `\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}`: Explicitly sets the seed for the pseudo-random number generator (see pgf manual).

Comment: Thank you very much! It works if the \pgfmathseed{} command is inserted within the multiframe environment.

Comment: I added a answer based on my comment. Please accept it, when it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem one can set a seed with:

```
\pgfmathsetseed{<integer>}
```

Description from the [PGF/TikZ-Manual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf): *Explicitly sets the seed for the pseudo-random number generator. By default it is set to the value of \time×\year.*